# Why do I receive an "RTMGRP_LINK undeclared" error even when "rtnetlink.h" is included?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, netlink

I have written a kernel module where I want to send interface up/down notifications to the user space program. I have assigned the message group as `RTMGRP_LINK` and also included `linux/rtnetlink.h` header file. But still when I compile the module I receive the following error:

```
abc.c: In function âevent_handlerâ:
abc.c:63: error: âRTMGRP_LINKâ undeclared (first use in this function)
abc.c:63: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
abc.c:63: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Can somebody suggest why?

Comment: RTMGRP_LINK macro is defined only to be used by user-mode programs. I could see that it is defined under "#ifndef \_\_KERNEL\_\_" macro

Comment: @Icarus3 Correct. After going through the kernel header once again I observed that RTMGRP_LINK is confined to user-space programs only as you said. For kernel modules RTNLGRP_LINK is to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the `linux/rtnetlink.h` header. I observed that `RTMGRP_LINK` is defined under `#ifndef __KERNEL__` which means that it can only be used by user-space programs. For Kernel modules `RTNLGRP_LINK` should be used to use the `NETLINK_ROUTE` family of Netlink Sockets for communication.